# ffmpeg get all sound devices(input/output)

Tags: audio, command-line, ffmpeg, device

I have downloaded the static build of `ffmpeg` for `Windows` and am trying to get all my sound devices (input/output) I have googled and found this [command to retrieve audio devices](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA) , but when I use it `ffmpeg arecord -l`, it shows this error

```
Unrecognized option 'l'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

what am missing here?

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: `arecord` is a separate command, you do just `arecord -l`.

Answer (score 11):

`arecord` is the command-line sound recorder and player for the ALSA soundcard driver which is available on Linux.

On Windows you can list the `dshow` devices with:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

See the Windows section of https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

Comment: how about linux? i end up with Unknown input format: 'dshow'

Comment: @ChenmingZhang https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA for example. You can find the supported devices in the documentation: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html

Comment: `Unrecognized option 'list_devices'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

Comment: "avfoundation" can be used instead of "dshow" on Mac OS, but I'm still looking for what I can use on Linux.

Comment: It shows only microphone... No speakers or stereo mix...